# Amigão vs amigo

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, substantivos

I've been learning European Portuguese for a few months and in the class, we always used *amigo* for a friend. But recently I've encountered the word *amigão*, which was also translated as a friend.

[Here in the online dictionary](https://dicionario.priberam.org/amig%C3%A3o) I've found that *amigão* = *grande amigo*, but a friend of mine (who is a beginner like me) claims that: *amigão = very good friend*.

So my question is: what does *amigão* really mean? Is it used to describe a friend who is literally big, or maybe a good friend, or a best friend, or maybe sth else? And what is the difference between *amigo* and *amigão*?

Comment: FWIW, in Brazilian Portuguese "amigão" is a (very) good friend, it never means a friend who is literally big.

Comment: I don’t interpret *grande amigo* as a big-sized friend. For me it means a *very good friend* indeed.

Comment: You could loosely translate amigão as buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AMIGÃO** - substantivo masculino.  In **pt-BR**

- Amigão is very informal, not everybody uses it, and it's a slang-word.
- You're not likely to hear it from an elderly person.
- Literally, "amigão" means a very good friend.
- In certain contexts, however, it ain't necessarily so.  It depends on when, why, and who says it.
- I can say that Pedro is "um amigão meu" and I am sincere, we are very good friends indeed.
- But I can also say "tu és um amigão", just to flatter someone, acting as a sycophant or not.
- In addition, I can also shout from my car window to a total stranger: "Hey **amigão**, can you tell how to get to the nearest gas station?"

The main difference between "amigo" and "amigão", however, is that the latter is **usually** informal, and used mostly by young and middle-aged guys. Some people say "amigaço" instead, and all the above applies to this word as well.